# My form POST doesn't recognize the POST input variables anymore, so isset always false

Tags: php, html, forms

My form always worked in the past, but when I tried to upload multiple images, it suddenly doesn't recognize the POST input anymore.

I've tried several things including: looking in PHP.INI to see if something's wrong, print_r the array to see what's in it (it's empty), making sure there's an action and name to the Input field and deleting the irrelevant javascript, but nothing seems to work. I'm sure I'm overlooking something but I've checked everything that I think could be wrong.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
 if ((isset($_POST['title'])) && (isset($_POST['title_small'])) &&        (isset($_POST['article_small'])) && (isset($_POST['article'])) && (!empty($_POST['title'])) && (!empty($_POST['title_small']))
&& (!empty($_POST['article_small'])) && (!empty($_POST['article'])))
{   
    include('../includes/database.php');
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $title_small = $_POST['title_small'];
    $article_small = $_POST['article_small'];
    $article = $_POST['article'];

    if($_FILES['file_array']['error'][0] == 0)
    {
        $name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
        $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
        $type_array = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
        $size_array = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];
        $error_array = $_FILES['file_array']['error'];
        $imgnames = implode(',', $name_array);

        for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++)
        {
            // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
             $check = getimagesize($tmp_name_array[$i]);
            if($check !== false) {
                echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
                $uploadOk = 1;
            } else {
                echo "File is not an image.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }

                // Check if file already exists
            $target_file = "../uploads/" . $name_array[$i];
            if (file_exists($target_file)) {
                echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
            // Check file size
            if ($size_array[$i] > 500000) {
                echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }

            $extensions = pathinfo($name_array[0], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            // Allow certain file formats
            if($extensions != "jpg" && $extensions != "JPG" && $extensions != "png" && $extensions != "jpeg" //AANPASSEN HOOFDLETTERS
            && $extensions != "gif" ) {
                echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
            }

            // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
            if ($uploadOk == 0) {
                echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
            // if everything is ok, try to upload file
            } 
            else 
            {
                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "../uploads/".$name_array[$i]))
                {
                    echo $name_array[$i]." upload is complete<br>";
                } 
                else
                {
                    echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]."<br>";
                }
            }
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO articles (title, title_small, article_small, article, image_article) VALUES ('$title', '$title_small', '$article_small', '$article', '$imgnames')";
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) 
        {
            header('location: ../paper.php');
        }
        else
        {
            echo "error:" . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }
    else
     {
        array_push($errors, "You forgot something!");
     }
   }
 }

?>
```

And the form:

```
      <form class="form" id="form1" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input name="title" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Title" maxlength="100"/>
        <input name="title_small" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Small Title" maxlength="100"/>
        <textarea name="article_small" class="feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Small Article"></textarea>
        <textarea name="article" class="feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Article"></textarea>
        <input type="file" name="file_array[]" accept="image/*" id="imguploadsmall" />
       <input type="submit" value="ADD" id="button-blue" name="submit" />
    </form>
   </div>
```

Edit: vardump:

```
  array (size=0)
  empty
  array (size=40)
 'HTTP_HOST' => string 'localhost' (length=9)
 'HTTP_CONNECTION' => string 'keep-alive' (length=10)
 'CONTENT_LENGTH' => string '14140480' (length=8)
 'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL' => string 'max-age=0' (length=9)
 'HTTP_ACCEPT' => string       'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' (length=74)
 'HTTP_ORIGIN' => string 'http://localhost' (length=16)
 'HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS' => string '1' (length=1)
 'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => string 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36' (length=110)
 'CONTENT_TYPE' => string 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary50iFmEAIoV7IB7mF' (length=68)
 'HTTP_REFERER' => string 'http://localhost/ded6/admin/add_article.php' (length=43)
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' => string 'gzip, deflate' (length=13)
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' => string 'nl,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,de;q=0.4,af;q=0.2,es;q=0.2,fr;q=0.2,zh-TW;q=0.2' (length=71)
 'HTTP_COOKIE' => string 'PHPSESSID=2mnctabpk7qd2v76v0k6l9h3q3' (length=36)
 'PATH' => string 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program    Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\In'... (length=1185)
   'SystemRoot' => string 'C:\WINDOWS' (length=10)
   'COMSPEC' => string 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe' (length=27)
   'PATHEXT' => string    '.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC' (length=53)
    'WINDIR' => string 'C:\WINDOWS' (length=10)
   'SERVER_SIGNATURE' => string '<address>Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80</address>
   ' (length=79)
    'SERVER_SOFTWARE' => string 'Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12' (length=31)
    'SERVER_NAME' => string 'localhost' (length=9)
    'SERVER_ADDR' => string '::1' (length=3)
    'SERVER_PORT' => string '80' (length=2)
    'REMOTE_ADDR' => string '::1' (length=3)
    'DOCUMENT_ROOT' => string 'C:/wamp/www/' (length=12)
    'REQUEST_SCHEME' => string 'http' (length=4)
    'CONTEXT_PREFIX' => string '' (length=0)
    'CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT' => string 'C:/wamp/www/' (length=12)
    'SERVER_ADMIN' => string 'admin@example.com' (length=17)
    'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => string 'C:/wamp/www/DED6/admin/add_article.php' (length=38)
    'REMOTE_PORT' => string '34620' (length=5)
    'GATEWAY_INTERFACE' => string 'CGI/1.1' (length=7)
    'SERVER_PROTOCOL' => string 'HTTP/1.1' (length=8)
    'REQUEST_METHOD' => string 'POST' (length=4)
    'QUERY_STRING' => string '' (length=0)
     'REQUEST_URI' => string '/ded6/admin/add_article.php' (length=27)
     'SCRIPT_NAME' => string '/ded6/admin/add_article.php' (length=27)
     'PHP_SELF' => string '/ded6/admin/add_article.php' (length=27)
     'REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT' => float 1463656788.598
     'REQUEST_TIME' => int 1463656788
```

Only error is:

```
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at C:\wamp\www\DED6\admin\add_article.php:2) in C:\wamp\www\DED6\includes\header.php on line 3
```

Comment: please check all these variables in php.ini "memory_limit 100MB", "post_max_size 100MB", "upload_max_filesize 100MB", "max_execution_time 3000" and then check @RickyR

Comment: `var_dump($_POST, $_SERVER);` at the beginning of the PHP file after submitting the form. Than give us the result here please. Not just saying "empty". Complete dump please.

Comment: Is there any error in your PHP error log file, something suggesting that a size limit is exceeded?

Comment: @BrijalSavaliya checked and nothing changed

Comment: @BrainFooLong Edited with the code you just posted, I have no idea what it's saying though

Comment: @RickyR where is session_start() ,and why you have used that  ?

Comment: @BrijalSavaliya I used session_start() in a header which I include on every page, because I always make use of sessions on every page. This isn't right, but I doubt it's the problem since the error persist even if I move session_start() or delete it. The if statement still sees no set POST input

Comment: @RickyR I recommend to create a new test file with just the form and a `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); var_dump($_POST, $_SERVER, $_FILES);` at top to find out if the error still exist with nothing else side-effecting it.

Comment: @BrainFooLong tried it in a new document, session on top and the error disappeared. However the POST input I get back is still not set

Comment: @RickyR So just one more thing i can think of, try remove `enctype="multipart...` and the `<input type="files"` field.

Comment: @BrainFooLong If I delete those the image upload doesn't work...

Comment: @RickyR Obsiously. It is just to test where the problem come from. If you get `$_POST` data when you remove the upload functionality than the problem must have something to do with that and you can search more exact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it has some restrictions on file related settings in php.ini. Try to upload very small sized files and check. php error log gives the detailed error information.